# Making form fields appear horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: html, css

I have a form that is appearing vertically:

```
<form action="roseresult.php" method="POST" id='rosesearch'>
<label>Latin Name:</label><input name='latin_name' type='text' />
<label>Common Name:</label><input name='common_name_name' type='text' /></br>
<label>Variety Type:</label><select name="variety">
            <option value="Any">Any</option>
            <option value="Climber/Rambler">Climber/Rambler</option>
            <option value="David Austin">David Austin</option>
            <option value="Floribunda">Floribunda</option>
            <option value="Groundcover">Groundcover</option>
            <option value="Hybrid Tea">Hybrid Tea</option>
            <option value="Patio/Miniature">Patio/Miniature</option>
            <option value="Shrub">Shrub</option></select>
<input name='search' type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
```

I have edited this in css to try and make it appear horizontally but it doesnt seem to work. I thought float:left; would do it but it doesnt.

CSS:

```
#rosesearch {
width:400px;
border-color:#7f2e3f;
padding: 5px 500px 5px 5px;
float:left;
}

#rosesearch legend {
background-color:#7f2e3f;
width:200px;
font-size: 20px;
}

#rosesearch label {
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
width:140px;
font-size:1.1em;
float:left;
color:#000000;
}

#rosesearch input {
font-size:12px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #000000;
width:244px;
margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
color:#000000;
float:left
}
```

Is there any other way I can make the form appear horizontally?

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle of your form as posted: http://jsfiddle.net/3Q7X4/. Are you trying to get these controls all in one row?

Comment: I have 9 fields - I want one them to appear side by side so in essense 5 rows with the last row having just one field if you know what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two obvious options:

1. Put each pair of inputs you want to be inline in one `<div>`,
   repeating these wrapper divs as rows until all your inputs are in
   the form, or
2. Create two "column" divs and then place the inputs in
       the order you need to match them up.

`#`1 will probably be the easiest, and most consistent. I'll update the fiddle I posted above to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/3Q7X4/5/

**HTML:**

```
<form action="roseresult.php" method="POST" id='rosesearch'>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="editor-cell">
            <label>Latin Name:</label>
            <input name='latin_name' type='text' />
        </div>
        <div class="editor-cell">
            <label>Common Name:</label>
            <input name='common_name_name' type='text' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="editor-cell">
            <label>Variety Type:</label>
            <select name="variety">
                <option value="Any">Any</option>
                <option value="Climber/Rambler">Climber/Rambler</option>
                <option value="David Austin">David Austin</option>
                <option value="Floribunda">Floribunda</option>
                <option value="Groundcover">Groundcover</option>
                <option value="Hybrid Tea">Hybrid Tea</option>
                <option value="Patio/Miniature">Patio/Miniature</option>
                <option value="Shrub">Shrub</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input name='search' type='submit' value='Search' />
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
form#rosesearch
{
    width:700px;
}

#rosesearch legend {
background-color:#7f2e3f;
width:200px;
font-size: 20px;
}

#rosesearch label {
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
width:140px;
font-size:1.1em;
float:left;
color:#000000;
}

#rosesearch input {
font-size:12px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #000000;
width:244px;
margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
color:#000000;
float:left
}

#rosesearch div.form-row
{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    overflow:auto;
    zoom:1;
}


#rosesearch div.form-row div.editor-cell
{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**EDIT:** Just updated the fiddle. It's fairly rough, but I hope you see what I was getting at.

Comment: Just did. Check the link (the version number is different). :)

Comment: thats it mate! but is there any way to get the field to appear next to the label?

Comment: Yeah: adjust the width of the `.editor-cell` rule to account for the label+input width. You'd also want to make sure the form is wide enough to allow both "cells" to sit side-by-side - might be easiest to remove the width rule for the form.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `#rosesearch` and `#rosesearch label` widths are not big enough to contain all your inputs horizontally.

You need to make the `width` bigger or remove and let the browser handle it.

Comment: Ok thanks mate but how do I get it so that the fields are aligned. They appear all over the place. And I want 5 fields on one side and 4 on the other.

Comment: You only have 3 fields in your example... Seriously?

Comment: that was just a smaller version of what I have mate. Not gonna put all the code on here am i?